# Does the DisplayPort on the Dell UltraSharp U2311H Monitor work with a MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, macbook, display, displayport, mini-displayport

I'm thinking of getting the Dell UltraSharp U2311H monitor which apparently comes with a DisplayPort. (I used the word "apparently" because I find DisplayPort support a little bit too good to be true, coming from Dell. But great news nonetheless if it's really true)

I plan to connect it to a Mac Book Pro (2010) via a mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable. Has anyone tried this setup? Does it work? Thanks.

Comment: DisplayPort is not an Apple-exclusive standard. [Dell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dell) shipped the first display with DisplayPort support in 2008. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: @Daniel Beck I plead ignorance and laziness. Cool, I got the impression it was an Apple thing because I never came across a PC that actually had a DisplayPort. (Not in the corporate environment at least) Thanks for pointing that out. ;-)

Comment: The problem is once you want to power a 30 inch DVI display (probably more common than the handful of DisplayPort out there). There are active adapters but -- at least that's what I heard -- they don't work too well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're more commonly found on newer video cards, but I have seen them on the more recent Dell PCs as well.

You shouldn't have a problem with what you are trying to accomplish though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works beautifully! My setup is slightly scaled down (2008 macbook pro & U2211H), but it should work as well or better.

I got a miniDP to DP cable (only $10 in Canada), because connecting through miniDP to VGA gives a poor image even at high resolutions (waves). I did not try to connect through DVI.

The colours will likely differ between monitors, but it can be dealt with using proper calibration (http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/calibrating.htm)

It's a nice setup; I hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

I just got a Dell u2311h (rev. A02) today and also a DisplayPort to Mini-DisplayPort direct 2 meter cable from Circuit Assembly and they both work beautifully with my MacBook Pro 13" 2011 and OS X 10.6.6.

Make sure you manually change the input source option to DisplayPort in the OSD in order for the computer to go to sleep. Otherwise, the input source auto-detection will keep waking up the laptop.

Other than this small consideration, no issues whatsoever.